# PHP date language library

Tags: php, date

Has noone made libraries for dates in other languages for PHP? As you can't rely on languages being installed on your system, a framework for formatting dates according to local languages must be something a lot of people can find use for. Maybe I'm just not very good a googling, because I can't find any...

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking but [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) is the only thing I could think of while reading that.

Comment: it exists natively, if you install the right langages http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Yes, but if you don't have shell access to the server (e.g. web hotel), you can't install anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php will listen to the language. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php for setting the language.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
echo strftime("%e %B");
```

Outputs:

> 5 juni

Comment: Ah - I have to use strftime. Thank you SO much! My language IS installed, after all... Still doesn't solve the problem, if it isn't, though...

Comment: It's a pity that there isn't an equivalent for DateTime objects though